# Snowflake regexp_replace not working as expected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to get paths enclosed by double quotes (ex: "path"."to"."element"). It also strips any bracket-enclosed array element references (like "[0]")

```
var path_name = "regexp_replace(regexp_replace("customers[0].name",'\\[(.+)\\]'),'(\\w+)','"\\1"')" ;
```

> I tried this method but it is displaying error

Comment: Hi, you haven't actually asked a question. You'll need to provide sample data and the result you want to achieve with that data in order for anyone to help you

Comment: Hi, I am trying to automate json views. I am using this tutorial.https://www.snowflake.com/blog/automating-snowflakes-semi-structured-json-data-handling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a really poorly written question. But lets play the guessing game anyways.

So you have a Javascript stored procedure, and you have that line it side it, and it doesn't work as you expect: lets guess it looks like:

```
create or replace procedure sp()
    returns VARCHAR
    language javascript
    as
    $$
    var txt = '"customers[0].name"';
    var sql_regexp1 = '\\\\[(.+)\\\\]';
    var sql_regexp2 = '(\\\\w+)';
    var sql_rep_2 = '\"\\\\1\"';
    
    var full_rep1 = "regexp_replace('" + txt + "','"+ sql_regexp1 +"')";
    var full_rep2 = "select regexp_replace(" + full_rep1 + ",'"+ sql_regexp2 +"','"+ sql_rep_2 + "');";
    //return full_rep2;
    
    var statement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: full_rep2} );
    var result_set1 = statement.execute();
    result_set1.next()
    return result_set1.getColumnValue(1);
    $$;
  ;
```

and if you uncomment out the early return to can see the `full_rep2`

thus you can test that the inner SQL

```
select regexp_replace('"customers[0].name"','\\[(.+)\\]');
```

gives:

| REGEXP_REPLACE('"CUSTOMERS[0].NAME"','\[(.+)\]') |
| --- |
| "customers.name" |

lets assume that's correct!

then you can check the outer replace:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('"customers[0].name"','\\[(.+)\\]'),'(\\w+)','"\\1"');
```

which gives:

| REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('"CUSTOMERS[0].NAME"','\[(.+)\]'),'(\W+)','"\1"') |
| --- |
| ""customers"."name"" |

and if we call the stored procedure:

```
call sp();
```

we get:

| SP |
| --- |
| ""customers"."name"" |

So this was "how I debugged the SQL/Javascript" to have "valid working SQL. The question then becomes, what output did you want. And can you get there from here.